# Using Replace function in VBA to alter SQL code with dimension field

Tags: sql, excel, vba, replace

I am using VBA in Excel and calling a stored SQL procedure from a file location. I am trying to alter the replace function so that the replacement value is a variable and not static. Within the replace code my lookup value is 'CurrentDBinCode' and my replacement is 'VariableDBName'. I have tried some code listed below but none has worked thus far.

```vb
Dim VariableDBName

If OperatingMode = "Test" Then
VariableDBName = "DB2"
ElseIf OperatingMode = "Live" Then
VariableDBName = "DB1"
End IF

sqlcommand = Replace(sqlcommand, "CurrentDBincode", "VariableDBName")
sqlcommand = Replace(sqlcommand, "CurrentDBincode", & "VariableDBName" &)
sqlcommand = Replace(sqlcommand, "CurrentDBincode", "&VariableDBName&")
sqlcommand = Replace(sqlcommand, "CurrentDBincode", "Value.VariableDBName")
```

I have tried several iterations to include value and cast but no luck.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask], then improve question! There are no stored procedures availible on Ms Excel, so specify your database! Also read on [Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/replace-function). I expect `CatalogM2M` value not being `"CatalogM2M"`, so you may want to use the value of `CatalogM2M` in Replace? Then use the variable not the string-literal.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code to as follows and it appears to be working.

'''
sqlcommand = Replace(sqlcommand, "CurrentDBincode", VariableDBName)
'''

Comment: Nice, you found the answers yourself! But you still mix up single-quotes(`'`) and backticks(`\``) . Only 3 backticks(`\`\`\``) start a code-block !. But why not use the tilde(`~ `) ? Easier to type (on german layout) and no risk of confusion. So use `~~~vba` to start a code-block (the vba tag after the tildes indicate syntax-highlighting to use `lang-vb` for highlighting.